# Where are persistence units in gs-accessing-data-jpa sample?

Tags: spring-data-jpa, persistence.xml

Here is an example of accessing Data with Spring JPA: http://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-data-jpa/

Where are any persistence units and/or persistence.xml files there?